# Converting string to double always gives me wrong representation

Tags: java, string, double

I want to convert this string  `"0.00071942446044"` to double by using `Double.parsedouble` method but it always gives this answer `7.1942446044E-4`

Is there any idea to convert it to double but keeping the same number as it is in the string?

Comment: You seem to think that a `double` "knows" about a string representation. It doesn't - it's just a value. If you want to format it in a particular way, you need to do so explicitly.

Comment: `7.1942446044E-4` and `0.00071942446044` *are* the same `double`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_notation

Comment: @LutzHorn so you mean , If I put these values in the array and do some comparison on that array the comparison answer will be right ??

Comment: Just be happy that the rightmost digit(s) are coincidentally identical - `double` is neither precise, nor mirrors exactly the notation in base 10 (500 * 0.2 is not 100.0).

Comment: If I compare this number  0.01223021582736  with 7.1942446044E-4 it will give that 0.01223021582736 is greater ???

Comment: Yes, because `7.1942446044E-4` is just a notation for `0.00071942446044` which is less than `0.01223021582736`. Hint: The `E` says how many digist to shift the decimal point to the left (`-`) or to the right (`+`).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `new BigDecimal(myString)`, this is not the same but will keep the same representation. It provides API for doing different math, but is slower than doing arithmetical operations with doubles.

Comment: actually I used this way to store the numbers in the file

Comment: doubles have limited space for fraction part (52 bits), BigDecimal has no limits (except java memory) and provides high precision math

Comment: but keep in your mind that I need to store these numbers in multidimintional double array to do some arithmatics operation on it .

Comment: if you need high precision you can create `BigDecimal[][]` array instead, if you need nice output you can use formatting as advised in answers below

Comment: My question to you is: If I compare this number 0.01223021582736 with 7.1942446044E-4 it will give that 0.01223021582736 is greater ???

Comment: @MonjedSeder Yes, and you can always check it - `System.out.println(0.01223021582736 > 7.1942446044E-4);` and on the other side `System.out.println(0.00001223021582736 < 7.1942446044E-4);`

Comment: `7.1942 E -4` is 7.1942 * 10^-4, so it is 0.00071942

Comment: Can I create an array of BigDecimal ??

Comment: @MonjedSeder Yes, but you should ask yourself whether you really need it, `BigDecimal` is very expensive in terms of memory and processing speed. I've written a ton of Java programs and I've only very rarely needed `BigDecimal`, `double` is most often sufficient (actually `float` (1/2 the size of `double`) would've most often been sufficient, but I tend to stick to `double`).

Comment: the string 0.00143884892088 is gives the same representation in double . why it does not write it in this way 1.438884992088 *10^-3

Comment: @MonjedSeder [This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double)) explains it.

Answer (score 3):

Although both numbers are exactly the same, you could use DecimalFormat to manipulate the format in a way you like, only for presentation purpose. Here is an example:

```
String s = "0.00071942446044";

Double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##############");

System.out.println("double: " + d);
System.out.println("formatted: " + df.format(d));
```

The out is:

```
double: 7.1942446044E-4
formatted: 0.00071942446044
```

Note that the number of # after decimal point is exactly the same as your example.

Comment: ,so when I do arithmatic operations and comparisons or sum to these numbers the answer will be correct??

Comment: Yes, 0.01 is exactly the same as 1 x 10 ^ -2. So any arithmetic operation will be the same for both numbers.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a different way of displaying the number. [The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28double%29) does a reasonable job of explaining it exactly.

If you simply want to print it in the same format you can use `printf` or `String.format`:

Prints `0.000719`:

```
System.out.printf("%f\n", Double.parseDouble("0.00071942446044"));
```

Prints `0.00071942446044`: (with hard-coded precision, which is probably not idea)

```
System.out.printf("%.14f\n", Double.parseDouble("0.00071942446044"));
```

Also note that numbers aren't stored in terms of digits, so you won't get an exact large-precision representation for floating point types (`float` and `double`) (though `double`, as you can see can handle this amount of digits). Notice what happens if you use `float`:

Prints `7.1942444`:

```
System.out.printf("%.7f\n", Float.parseFloat("7.1942446"));
```

Similar test case for `double`: (prints `7.1942446044352310`)

```
System.out.printf("%.16f\n", Double.parseDouble("7.1942446044352312"));
```

If you want greater precision (at a price, obviously - memory and speed), you should use `BigDecimal`.